# iPhone . delegates and properties

Tags: iphone, delegates, uitableview

I have a viewController (lets call it vcA) and this viewController has a NSArray property declared and synthesized.

```
NSArray *myProperty;

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myProperty;
```

and then synthesized on .m

this vcA is a delegate for another viewController, vcB.

Inside vcB I do:

```
NSArray *getMyPropertyFromDelegate = (NSArray *)[delegate myProperty];
```

and I receive an error saying **warning: Semantic Issue: Instance method '-myProperty' not found (return type defaults to 'id')**

I know I can silent this warning changing the line to

```
NSArray *getMyPropertyFromDelegate = (NSArray *)[(vca*)delegate myProperty];
```

and importing vcA.h, but I am trying to make vcB as independent as possible, because the delegate can change.

How do I do that working just with the delegate property?

thanks

Comment: Yep, protocols were invented to solve for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write a custom protocol.

Make `vca` view controller conforming to the protocol, and in `vcB`, declare the delegate property :

```
@property(retain) id <MyProtocol> delegate;
```

This means the delegate can be any type, as long as it conforms to `MyProtocol`.

[Here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) is an example.

```
// MyProtocol.h
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@property(retain) NSArray *myProperty;

@end

// vca.h
@interface vca : XXXX <MyProtocol> {
....
}
@property(retain) NSArray *myProperty;


// vca.m
@synthesize myProperty; // or provide a getter
```

Comment: vcA's delegate is being declared like this.

Comment: also declare the property in the protocol

Comment: as long as the property is declared in the protocol and the delegate must conform to it, you shouldn't have any warning

Comment: but I am having. It thinks myProperty is a method.

Comment: does the delegate synthesizes or implements a getter ?

Comment: while the protocol only declare the property, the view controller that conforms to it must either synthesize the property, or implement it.

Comment: I don't get it. vcB must synthesize vcA's property????? I don't have a clue on how to do that. Things will be clear if you can rewrite your answer to give an example. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments to Vince's solution, I would say you need to learn a little about protocols as they are (almost?) always used with the concept of delegate.

You can start with http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html
Nice simple code, rich in comments.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html for the official Apple documentation.